# Sort Dictionary without pandas

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
test = {
    "Name": ["Bimal", "Kamal", "Hari", "Ram", "Shyam"],
    "Age": [12, 24, 23, 19, 17]
}
```

and I want to sort it based on `name` so that the age of `Kamal` must remain 24 after sorting.
So, what I want as final dictionary is:

```
test = {
    "Name": ["Bimal", "Hari", "Kamal", "Ram", "Shyam"],
    "Age": [12, 23, 24, 19, 17]
}
```

I can easily do it with `pandas` but I wanted an efficient way to do it without using pandas. Is there any way to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `zip` method.

```
test = {
   "Name": ["Bimal", "Kamal", "Hari", "Ram", "Shyam"],
   "Age": [12, 24, 23, 19, 17]
}

print(*zip(*sorted(zip(test["Name"], test["Age"]))))
```

The result of this will consists in two tuples and then you can convert to lists.

```
result = list(zip(*sorted(zip(test["Name"], test["Age"]))))
test = {
  "Name": list(result[0]),
  "Age": list(result[1])
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about taking the indices of each list items before and after and sort other key values accordingly! but that was too much time and space consuming process!